# How to customize the colour of a string that contains a URL?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm making a new theme for VScode and I wanna change the color of a string that contains a URL. But I can't find a scope of it.

Comment: You can use the `Inspect Scopes` command from the Command Palette but I doubt for most languages there will be a separate scope for `url`s as they may be just strings.  You may have to make your own regex to detect them.

Comment: I tried using the Inspect Scopes but the url has the same scope as string.